# How to mock test a Node.js CLI with Jest?

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I'm stuck at the very beginning, simply requiring the CLI and capturing its output. I've tried two methods but both don't work.

This is my cli.js:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

console.log('Testing...');
process.exit(0);
```

And this my cli.test.js:

```
test('Attempt 1', () => {
    let stdout = require("test-console").stdout;
    let output = stdout.inspectSync(function() {
        require('./cli.js');
    });
    expect(output).toBe('Testing...');
});

test('Attempt 2', () => {
    console.log = jest.fn();
    require('./cli.js');
    expect(console.log.calls).toBe(['Testing...']);
});
```

Doesn't really matter which test is actually being run, the output is always:

```
$ jest

 RUNS  bin/cli.test.js
Done in 3.10s.
```

Comment: I suppose that's because of process.exit. Try to stub it.

Comment: You're absolutely right, thanks! And that's also the problem in my actual project where I use commander. This line here: https://github.com/tj/commander.js/blob/dcddf698c5463795401ad3d6382f5ec5ec060478/index.js#L1157

Comment: Of course... I guess I can simply use outputHelp() instead of help().

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Node.js CLI applications are no different to other applications except their reliance on environment. They are expected to extensively use `process` members, e.g.:

- `process.stdin`
- `process.stdout`
- `process.argv`
- `process.exit`

If any of these things are used, they should be mocked and tested accordingly.

Since `console.log` is called directly for output, there's no problem to spy on it directly, although helper packages like `test-console` can be used too.

In this case `process.exit(0)` is called in imported file, so spec file early exits, and next `Done` output is from parent process. It should be stubbed. Throwing the error is necessary so that code execution is stopped - to mimic the normal behavior:

```
test('Attempt 2', () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    jest.spyOn(process, 'exit').mockImplementationOnce(() => {
      throw new Error('process.exit() was called.')
    });

    expect(() => {
      require('./cli.js');
    }).toThrow('process.exit() was called.');
    expect(spy.mock.calls).toEqual([['Testing...']]);
    expect(process.exit).toHaveBeenCalledWith(0);
});
```

Comment: Would you mind adding an example for intercepting process.stdout? Because the return of test-console is unusable (possibly because jest hooks into stdout and adds colors and metadata to the output?) and process.stdout.on('data', ...) causes a "read ENOTCONN" error when used in a test.

Comment: I didn't do that with Jest, so I'm not aware of pitfalls. I guess that's known issue, https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1120 , and spying on console methods is right thing to do. It seems like Jest messes with std* streams. I guess a workaround is to run tested script with child_process and read from its stdout (will likely be cumbersome because you need wrapper script to provide mocks for original script). Looks like complex problem that deserves a separate question if that's your case.

Comment: Ah, I see - wasn't aware of what Jest's output looks like in verbose mode. The problem with console is that some packages might write to stdout directly: https://github.com/tj/commander.js/blob/dcddf698c5463795401ad3d6382f5ec5ec060478/index.js#L1145
Makes me wonder whether that's good code design and should maybe be reported. At any rate - thanks for that link!

Comment: Makes sense. I guess you may want to mock Command.prototype.outputHelp instead.

Comment: Suppressing errors with try...catch isn't a good practice in a spec. There may be other errors that will result in no feedback. Since there is specific error, it should be asserted with toThrow.