# How do I test a Node.JS Script that is not a module and runs as soon as it's called?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, scripting, jestjs

I like to use Javascript as a replacement for bash scripts.

Assuming a contrived script called *start.js* that is run using `node start.js`:

```js
const shelljs = require("shelljs")

if (!shelljs.which("serve")) {
  shelljs.echo("'serve' is missing, please run 'npm ci'")
  process.exit(1)
}

shelljs.exec("serve -s build -l 3000")
```

How do I test that:

1. If `serve` isn't available then `serve -s build -l 3000` is never called and program exits with code 1.
2. If `serve` is available then `serve -s build -l 3000` is called.

I don't mind mocking "shelljs", `process.exit` or anything else.

My main issue is figuring out how to `require` or `import` such a functionless and moduleless file in a test suite and get it to run once on each separate test with the mocks present **without** actually turning this into a CommonJS/ES6 module.

Comment: This should likely be tested as e2e test, i.e. calling it with exec in separate process. You'll potentially have hard time dealing with `process.exit` in test scope. If you need to mock some destructive things, use `node -r` to import a file that does this (not related to Jest mocking).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just mock `shelljs` module, and spy `process.exit` function.

```
describe("start.js", () => {
  let shelljs
  let exitSpy

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.mock("shelljs", () => {
      return {
        exec: jest.fn(),
        which: jest.fn(),
        echo: jest.fn(),
      }
    })
    shelljs = require("shelljs")
    exitSpy = jest.spyOn(process, "exit").mockImplementation(() => {})
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules()
    jest.resetAllMocks()
  })

  it("should execute process.exit with code is 1 when 'serve' is not existed", () => {
    shelljs.which.mockReturnValue(false)

    require("./start")

    expect(shelljs.which).toHaveBeenCalledWith("serve");
    expect(shelljs.echo).toHaveBeenCalledWith("'serve' is missing, please run 'npm ci'")
    expect(exitSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1)
    // expect(shelljs.exec).toHaveBeenCalled() // can not check like that, exitSpy will not "break" your code, it will be work well if you use if/else syntax
  });

  it("should execute serve when 'serve' is existed", () => {
    shelljs.which.mockReturnValue(true)

    require("./start")

    expect(shelljs.which).toHaveBeenCalledWith("serve");
    expect(shelljs.echo).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
    expect(exitSpy).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
    expect(shelljs.exec).toHaveBeenCalledWith("serve -s build -l 3000")
  });
})
```

Another way to make sure the production code with be break when `process.exit` is called. Mock `exit` function throw an Error, then expect `shelljs.exec` will not be called

```
describe("start.js", () => {
  let shelljs
  let exitSpy

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.mock("shelljs", () => {
      return {
        exec: jest.fn(),
        which: jest.fn(),
        echo: jest.fn(),
      }
    })
    shelljs = require("shelljs")
    
    exitSpy = jest.spyOn(process, "exit").mockImplementation(() => {
      throw new Error("Mock");
    })
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules()
    jest.resetAllMocks()
  })

  it("should execute process.exit with code is 1 when 'serve' is not existed", () => {
    shelljs.which.mockReturnValue(false)

    expect.assertions(5)
    try {
      require("./start")
    } catch (error) {
      expect(error.message).toEqual("Mock")
    }

    expect(shelljs.which).toHaveBeenCalledWith("serve");
    expect(shelljs.echo).toHaveBeenCalledWith("'serve' is missing, please run 'npm ci'")
    expect(exitSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1)
    expect(shelljs.exec).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
  });

  it("should execute serve when 'serve' is existed", () => {
    shelljs.which.mockReturnValue(true)

    require("./start")

    expect(shelljs.which).toHaveBeenCalledWith("serve");
    expect(shelljs.echo).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
    expect(exitSpy).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
    expect(shelljs.exec).toHaveBeenCalledWith("serve -s build -l 3000")
  });
})
```

Comment: This works! But the problem here is that in the actual code, `process.exit(1)` stops running the script at that point. But since it's spied on in the test it just keeps executing code further down. Any way to stop that?

Comment: Found [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50379916/how-to-mock-test-a-node-js-cli-with-jest) that does exactly what you did here i.e. throw an exception on the spy.

I would prefer you just kept your bottom solution and used `expect().toThrow()` but this is definitely the correct answer and solved my problem so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

another way is to, extract the script into a function, add the function to another file, and test the other file properly.

So basically, create a `helper.js`:

```
const shelljs = require("shelljs")

function helper() {
  if (!shelljs.which("serve")) {
    shelljs.echo("'serve' is missing, please run 'npm ci'")
    process.exit(1)
  }

  shelljs.exec("serve -s build -l 3000")
}

module.exports = helper;
```

then in `start.js`:

```
const helper = require('./helper');

helper();
```

Now you can test the `helper.js` the normal way, and I think it's ok to not test `start.js`